# Evil twin httpd caused by failed Roundcube installation

Tags: apache, centos, httpd, webmail

**Note: I originally asked this on Server Fault and was told it was against the rules for mentioning Webuzo, so please do not ask me to take it there.**

**System:** VPS running CentOS 7 and Webuzo. httpd and sendmail had both been configured, but I wanted to add Roundcube for webmail.

**Backstory:** I first tried installing Roundcube from the command line. I attempted to follow [these instructions](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-latest-version-of-roundcube-centos-7/) but when I put Roundcube in my document root directory, I still got a 404.

I uninstalled the maria-db server and mysql packages, and then went to Webuzo to try to install it there. I was able to locate the installation page but got the error `Database is not posted`. I was unable to find any explanation of this error. My best guess is a necessary database port is blocked by my firewall, but I have no way to find out what the port number should be.

**The problem:** This afternoon, I discovered I was getting 404 errors for pages that had previously been accessible. httpd reported that it was unable to run due ot the port already being in use. I killed the process listening on port 80, then ran `systemctl start httpd`, but that didn't fix anything. Moreover, when that was running, Webuzo reported that the Apache server was actually stopped.

After more investigation, I found there was an extra copy of httpd that was now registered with systemctl. My guess is that something imported with the Roundcube-related packages brought it along. Stopping that and running the Webuzo version restored home-directory Web pages. I had to edit `webuzoVH.conf` to get my `DocumentRoot` setting fixed.

**My questions:**

1. Can I just delete the directory with the extra httpd? I'm leery of running an uninstall command.
2. How do I get systemctl back in touch with the correct httpd?
3. How *do* I install Roundcube (or any other webmail, at this point), ideally without destroying anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about server administration.

Comment: As the note up top says, I tried asking it as a server administration question first, only to be told it was not allowed there.

Comment: Just because it isn't allowed there, it doesn't mean it is on-topic here.  I would also close this as "too broad" because you ask multiple questions per post.

Comment: It's all from the same cause though. Unless I'm mistaken, in which case I would accept an explanation of how I misconstrued two separate things.

Comment: And if a question about httpd isn't on topic for web administration, where *is* it on topic?